# UITableViewCell subclass, move label to make room for checkmark, when tapped

Tags: ios, uitableview

So, i have subclassed UITableViewCell, that has a label to the far left, and another to the far right. When tapped, it should slide in the right label, and add a checkmark.

The checkmark thing works, but is placed right on top of the label.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{

    if ([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType; == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 
    {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }else
    {
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use inbuilt checkmark, because you have encroached the predefined place for checkmark by a label on far right. Use custom checkmark, and do you stuff.

Comment: Hos would solve the positioning like that?